# Can a I run a job every 5 mins using IE or Chrome

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, macros

I need to check a webservice is working correctly every 5 minutes.

To do this I want to enter login info - and login. on the next page I want to enter data into a form and press submit. then on the next page I want to log out. I want to then repeat this every 5 minutes. I also would like to record the times it takes to run the task from start to finish.

Is it possible to set up a macro like this on IE or Chrome? If so how?

Thanks

Comment: Weren't cron jobs meant to run on server without any browser intervention being required?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout  but why would you want to do this in a browser? a server-side script run via cron would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind doing a little programming to get there, you can use [Selenium WebDriver](http://seleniumhq.org/) to do this.

Comment: This seems top be the best option. Thanks